# Dockerized NodeJS in Fargate can't generate a working AWS pre-signed URL

Tags: node.js, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a dockerized NodeJS application, and I put the image in AWS ECR. It is working well running on my local environment with docker-compose, I can generate a pre-signed PUT URL. The pre-signed URL also works, I can upload object into it.
I tried to run the same ECR image with ECS Fargate, however I can't PUT the object into the generated pre-signed URL. I get an access denied error.

Edit:
I suspect the issue comes from IAM Role and Permission. I build the ECS Fargate infrastructure through CloudFormation, but it seems the role is properly set-up:

```
ECSTaskExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub "${ContainerName}-ECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
      Path: /
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Resource:
                  - !Ref DBHostSSMARN
                  - !Ref DBPortSSMARN
                  - !Ref DBUsernameSSMARN
                  - !Ref DBPasswordSSMARN
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - "ssm:GetParameters"
                  - "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
                  - "kms:Decrypt"
              - Resource: "*"
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - cloudwatch:*
                  - ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer
                  - ecr:BatchGetImage
                  - ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability
              - Resource:
                  - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${VideoRepoName}
                  - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${VideoRepoName}/*
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - s3:*
```

Comment: Most likely reason: when running locally your presign the url with your credentials, when running on ecs you presign with the credentials of the instance which presumably do not have the necessary permissions.

Comment: @luk2302 thanks for the suggestion! I've suspected the issues come around from the permission. I've tried to use the "*" in the resource but it still does not work. Probably I need to take a bit of rest to cool off my head...

Comment: If that is not enough you need to go through https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/ e.g. check KMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've assigned the S3 permission to a wrong role. I am supposed to give the S3 permission to the [*Task Role*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html), not the [*Task Execution Role*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html).